# How to update data in the user information list when using FBA

Tags: forms-authentication, 2007, user-profile, profile-sync

I've got to support a SharePoint web application which uses FBA with a custom membership and a custom role provider to authenticate the user against two different LDAPs. The user data are only stored in the user information lists. The SSP user profiles are not used.

Now one of the users got married and therefore her surname got changed in the LDAP (the one where her information are stored). But this change doesn't get provisioned into the user information list.

I wondering what option I have to provision changes of user data to the user information list. I've already tried to update the last name of the user manually, but it seems as if certain information like surname, first name are not editable in the user information list. I tried to edit them as a site administrator.

So what option do I have to solve this problem? Being able to edit the information per hand would also be a solution but of course not the most preferred one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do this. I have had the same difficulty when not using user profiles for FBA users. A friend of mine, Mark Rackley, who is a developer, wrote a program to address the issue. You can find it here: http://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxuZY7Z-yCdpNTQxZjY1OWQtMDRlYS00MDM3LWI1N2MtMmZlN2Q5MmU1ZjJh&hl=en

Comment: That's what I feared. But thanks for the tool I will have a look at it.